# The language of the “farewell-blessing” of Moshe

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, moshe-rabbeinu, parashat-vezot-habracha

In Moshe’s final blessing to Klal Yisrael (parashas Vezos HaBeracha, Devarim 33:1), the Torah says:

> וְזֹ֣את הַבְּרָכָ֗ה אֲשֶׁ֨ר בֵּרַ֥ךְ מֹשֶׁ֛ה אִ֥ישׁ הָאֱלֹהִ֖ים אֶת־בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל לִפְנֵ֖י מוֹתֽוֹ
>
> This is the blessing with which Moshe, G-d’s agent, bade the
> Israelites farewell before he died.

Here, Moshe is talking. The Torah says “Vezos HaBeracha Asher Berach Moshe”. But, a few pesukim further (Devarim 33:4), the Torah talks in another form:

> תּוֹרָ֥ה צִוָּה־לָ֖נוּ מֹשֶׁ֑ה - When Moshe charged us with the Torah

Notice the form "when Moshe charged **us**".

These were the words of Moshe, then why does the Torah states this in the perspective of Klal Yisrael and not "Torah Tzivu Lanu Mi Ani". Why is this?

Are there meforshim  who explain the reason (deeper meaning) behind this change in language in the Torah?

Comment: He seems to be changing to talking from the perspective of the *benei yisrael*. The same for *va'yehi bi'yeshurun melech* which possibly refers to himself. Maybe that is the biggest *berachah*, that the *benei yisrael* should appreciate the Torah, *ve'lo nasan lachem lev ladaas.. ad hayom hazeh* (see Rashi there).

Comment: That's a nice idea, but I am not sure if that answers the question completely. Why changing?

Comment: Maybe Moshe in stepping down assumed the role of one of the *benei yisrael*.

Answer (score 0):

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.33.3?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=en) to the previous verse answers your question. This verse is said in the voice of the Jewish people, quoting their words.